# find the angle of transformation through perspective transform matrix

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I have got a 3*3 matrix after applying perspective transform function, i want to find out the angle of rotation through transform matrix.
I got this 3*3 matrix:

```
[[ 3.89007777e+00 -9.00480966e-02 -9.29332376e+02]
 [-3.47394211e-01  3.27758886e+00 -3.55127508e+02]
 [ 1.33714080e-03 -4.37819257e-04  1.00000000e+00]]
```

Suggest me a path by which i can find the angles in all three direction.

Comment: Not that simple, since there are 3 rotations in 3D (roll, pitch and yaw) and perspective, scale and translation. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#decomposehomographymat and https://docs.rs/opencv/0.23.0/opencv/calib3d/index.html

Comment: See perhaps https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga54a2f5b3f8aeaf6c76d4a31dece85d5d

Comment: Thanks, but i want the angle. Can you calculate the angle from above matrix?

Comment: There is the function `RQDecomp3x3()` which can be used to find the Euler angles (https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1aaacb6224ec7b99d34866f8f9baac83). "Note, there is always more than one sequence of rotations about the three principal axes that results in the same orientation of an object, e.g. see [199] . Returned three rotation matrices and corresponding three Euler angles are only one of the possible solutions."

Answer (score 0):

If you have matrix named rqmtx:

```
phi = math.atan2(rqmtx[2][1], rqmtx[2][2])
psi = math.atan2(rqmtx[1][0], rqmtx[0][0])

if math.cos(psi) == 0:
    thetaa = math.atan2(-rqmtx[2][0], (rqmtx[1][0]/math.sin(psi)))
else:
    thetaa = math.atan2(-rqmtx[2][0], (rqmtx[0][0]/math.cos(psi)))
    
s = math.atan2(rqmtx[0][0], -math.sqrt(rqmtx[2][1]*rqmtx[2][1] + rqmtx[2][2]*rqmtx[2][2]))

pi = 22/7

phid = phi*(180/pi)
thetaad = thetaa*(180/pi)
psid = psi*(180/pi)
```